# Create milliseconds from Unix epoch to the current time

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am requesting a third party api. Which is a put request in which many parameters are going in body. Url is

https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/031limit_order

It also required **tonce** as a parameter, which says "**Tonce is a timestamp with a positive Interger that represents the number of milliseconds from Unix epoch to the current time. Error between tonce and server time can not exceed plus or minus 60s**".

I have tried creating tonce like the following ways:

```
long tonce = new Date().getTime();
long tonce = Instant.now();  
long tonce = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000L;
long tonce = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

but nothing worked, and in response, I am getting the following error :

**"message": "tonce check error, correct tonce should be within one minute of the current time"**

I don't know what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: The second doesn't compile. The third is microseconds, not milliseconds. The last one is the obvious, correct way. Either the documentation is wrong (maybe is requires seconds, not millis), or you simply have a clock that is offset by more than 1 minute compared to the API server. Or maybe you're not sending the tonce parameter correctly.

Comment: new java.util.Date().getTime() worked for me.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()`  - but sure you have compared the time of the computer with the one of the server?! and double-checked the request is correctly formed?? and maybe also inspect the logs of the server to check that everything is being received correctly (assuming that is available)??

Comment: @S.K. have you implemented the same api of coinex ? the link i have mentioned above!

Comment: also check the [System Time](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/049time) request that apparently returns the actual server time (maybe use that to compare with time obtained above)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger how to do i compare the time with there server ? Also i cannot check their logs. I am just following their documentation.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger how do i use their System Time request.? they have not mention any url there.

Comment: @Abhishek saini you can check your time with NTP server. I updated my answer.

Comment: you can also try another request that returns time, like described at [Acquire Market Statistics](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/021ticker) - has https URL

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i have tried that by postman, and sent the same timestamp they return, same error :(

Comment: what i am thinking they need as integer and i am sending as long value in milliseconds. What u suggest ?

Comment: I sent a request from postman with tonce as a weird value first (which gave tonce error) and then with new Date().getTime(); value and the error went away

Comment: @S.K. did u hit the same api of placing order ?

Comment: maybe you can copy&paste the request you are sending into the question... anyway it must be a long (by the documentation), neither a string (no quotes) nor a floating point number (no dot or comma).

Comment: @Abhisheksaini Yes. I hit the following url https://api.coinex.com/v1/order/limit

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem:

Your clock time is not correct.

You can check your time with NTP servers like `time.google.com` or `time.apple.com` automatically before your request.

Comment: If you are using windows, it only synchronizes once a week even if set up by default. I suggest synchronizing every few minutes (once an hour at worst) +1

Comment: @Ehsan i am using ubuntu and I have checked like ntpdate -q time.google.com  , which is returning the time same as my system time.